# Linkedin Posts API targetAudience does not have effect

Tags: linkedin-api

we are setting the interfaceLocales config to only make the post visible to a certain linkedin user language. We check if audience count is >= 300. When we submit the post there is no error.

But on Linkedin the post is visible for every browser language.

When i do a native post on linkedin, and set the audience targeting manually, after submitting the post and edit it again, it shows "All". So something the feature is not really working.

Does anybody has some more infos? I dont find any documentation, except the audience count of >= 300.

Thanks